# Evaluating limits restricted to real field with sagetex

Tags: sagetex

I am trying to use sagetex to calculate some limits and it is having difficulties with the branch cuts for roots. Specifically, things like (-1)^(1/3) won't simplify to -1, presumably because it's on the branch cut. All the limits that I want to calculate are for real valued functions, but I can't seem to figure out how to convince sagetex that is the case. I can use

```
assume(x,'real')
```

But this only tells sagetex that the input is real, so it still doesn't assume the output is real. This command won't work on the function itself.

For example;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
f(x) = (x + 1)/(x^(1/3)+1)
ans=limit(f(x), x=-1)
\end{sagesilent}
\sage{ans}
\end{document}
```

Running this gives an output of 0, when in fact the limit should be 3 (using sum of cubes). I can only assume this is a result of the branch cut issue as it only happens on negative reals.

Is there a way to redefine the branch cut, or better yet, tell sagetex that f is a real valued function and to use the real valued cube root and not the complex one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the [recognized annoyances with Sage](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/12074) that lacks a simple solution. There are several possibilities depending on the type of problem which are discussed [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/10730/is-there-a-simple-way-to-deal-with-computing-real-nth-roots-for-n-a-natural-number/) but I think the solution for your specific problem is handled as is mentioned on [this page](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/plot.html?highlight=sign):

```
f(x) = (x + 1)/(sign(x)*abs(x)^(1/3)+1)
limit(f(x), x=-1)
```

The abs(x) takes the absolute value of x thereby making sure the answer will be real. Then sign(x) of x puts a negative sign onto the answer, if x is negative. Running this through Sage without using the `assume` command will give you the limit of 3. Awkward but it works. That seems to be the solution that is recommended [here](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/11458).